# Wifi Adapter can see AP, but cannot connect

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

My wifi card is: Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

My problem is that when I attempt to connect to a wifi network it refuses the connection and requests I input the correct password. I have reset the router, confirmed the password, and checked for possible configuration issues on that end but everything is normal and all other devices are functional in regards to wifi.

Edit: pastebin of wireless-info script results - http://pastebin.com/Aa8T2Rn4

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I edited my answer after I first posted it so make sure to reload your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to get a new driver to try to fix the issue you are having:

Install the dependencies required to compile the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

No internet:

On another computer [go here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) Select Trusty in the drop-down box. Search for linux-headers-generic, build-essential and dkms. Be sure to locate their dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies.

Download the correct version, either 32- or 64-bit. Once you've download about seventeen packages on another computer, transfer them with a USB stick to the desktop of the computer with Ubuntu on it. Then do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then:

Go [here](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) and download the driver 3.15-rc1-1 to your computer then place the file on your desktop and right click and extract here.

Then compile the driver using the directions below.

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath9k 
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

When you have an upgrade to the kernel you will need to do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath9k 
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't currently have any sort of internet on the computer I'm attempting to get working, so the first bit isn't quite possible for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be a nightmare to try to get all the dependencies required without a connection, can you take it somewhere and connect it to an ethernet wire? Can you tether your cell phone? I will look for a way to install the dependencies without an connection it will take sometime.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to any other source of Internet. My router is similar to a wifi hotspot in that it does not have any open ethernet ports, connecting to the WAN via a coaxial connection over mocha. If there is another version of Ubuntu that I can download that won't have this problem I can do that.

Comment: You could download ubuntu 12.04 then for best results we will have to set a driver parameter most likely.

Comment: I added the directions to download the dependencies required to compile to a flash drive and then install them.